# How to subtract 1 from a column in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, with one column as factor. I want to subtract 1 from all rows in my column, but when i try i get an error message that " - " is not meaningful for factors.

How can i do this?

Comment: try transforming the factor into integer or numeric and reverse it after subtracting 1.

Comment: You can try this to convert factor to integer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information

Answer (score 1):

Factors aren't numbers even though there is a numbering system under them. Thus, when you try to substract 1 from factor levels, software will error. This is a logic error, not a software error.

Did you want factors, or was your data converted to factors when you imported it? If you want numeric data, you can convert factors to numbers by using [one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information).